# Slow scene strip playback in VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor, scene, cache

I animated a lot of scenes then added them into the VSE.
They were laggy and overall slow. So I looked it up on the internet
and someone told me about cache. I tried it and it were a bit faster, but still slow. I feel like, it's still an easy way to fix this, but if it isn't. I may just be stuck

[image: When I Play it With Cache]

As you can see with a simple non animated cube, I get 5 FPS

How to remake this error:

1.Start up a new blend file

2.Make a new scene

3.Go into VSE

4.Add the original scene

5.Play it

6.Press N

7.Go to cache

8.Cache should be ON

9.play it again.

**It will still be laggy**

I hope someone can tell me how to fix this

PC Specs: 300E 4GB RAM 32GB Lenovo Chromebook

my Blender Version: 3.6.5

Comment: My hardware had better specifications a few years ago and the VSE was still laggy... which is why I switched to DaVinci Resolve for video editing. I might be wrong, but I don't assume you will have much chance for smooth playback with this configuration. Minimum requirements were 64-bit quadcore CPU with 8 GB RAM and a graphics card with at least 2 GB VRAM if I remember correctly.

Comment: oh. well I cant use Davinci for Blender Scenes.. do u know anyone or have anything that could help me

Comment: I would use the VSE to arrange rendered image sequences. As soon as they are rendered, they are no longer render scenes, just images. Then you can use any video editing software for them. But no, I don't know anybody who can help. As I said, your hardware doesn't meet the _minimum_ requirements for just working with Blender. Let alone the _recommended_ specs if you wanted to work with a better performance.